# Jumps vs. Leaps

Tags: word-choice, nouns, meaning-in-context

Does a curve in science or finance have sudden jumps or sudden leaps? We talk about a discontinuous curve. My position is that jumps is more appropriate but I might be wrong.

Comment: Do you have an example of the graph?

Answer (score 1):

[Googling arxiv.org](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=site%3a+arxiv.org+%22sudden+jumps%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=site%3aarxiv.org+%22sudden+jumps%22&rls=en), a repository of mainly physics, math, and computer science papers, gives 768 hits for "sudden jumps" and five for "sudden leaps". I would recommend using "sudden jumps", although if you want to be more formal, you could also simply use "discontinuities".

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct term might be **step**. In mathematics, the graph of a **step function** or **staircase function** resembles the steps of of a stairs. If you have a curve with sudden jumps or leap, calling them **steps** would be consistent with standard mathematical terminology.

The phrase **step change** is derived from this mathematical concept and is widely used.

References:

http://www.icoachmath.com/math_dictionary/Step_Function.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/step_change

Comment: A ***step function*** has perfectly flat sections between the sudden jumps. I don't think *steps* gives the right impression.

Comment: A "sudden step"?

Answer (score 0):

To me leap implies a movement outward - horizontal.  Jump implies a movement up (although it can be taken either way) - so it would be for vertical.  So I guess if you are trying to convey a horizontal or vertical function.